# Page requires HTTP; ASP.NET authorization requires HTTPS

Tags: asp.net

On an ASP.NET website hosted on Azure, I need to secure a page so that only certain users can access it. Because of a javascript library used in the page, it will work correctly only when served over HTTP, but the ASP.NET authentication will not allow access unless the page is served over HTTPS.

To limit access to the secure page, I added a Web.config file to the folder containing the page:

```
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow roles="Admin" />
       <allow roles="Map Viewer" />
       <deny users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

The main web.config file sets up forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login/"
         requireSSL="true"
         timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This works like a charm if you access the secured page through https (e.g. https://example.com/Map). You are prompted to log in, you enter your credentials, and then you go to the page. As noted above, the page will not work correctly if served over http. However, ASP.NET authentication/authorization won't allow you to access it:
1. If you are not logged in and try to access the page over http, you are redirected to the site home page once you log in.
2. If you are logged in and try to access the page over http, you are shown the log in screen even though you are already logged in.

No other secure pages on the site require HTTP to work correctly, and this form-based authentication process has been working fine for those pages for years.

Comment: Why does the javascript library require HTTP? I'm skeptical of that, but if it's really true you should fire that library and find a replacement.

Comment: [link](https://cartodb.com/) doesn't serve their library over HTTPS--it falls back to HTTP. I tried copying the JS library to my server, but the map tiles loaded by the library won't come over HTTPS either.

Comment: For me, that would be enough to drop CartoDB, as they appear to not be serious about security

Comment: My recommendation for other users with this problem is to consider ASP.NET MVC, which allows the user to more easily move from HTTPS to HTTP. Beware that this has security implications! If a malicious user is able to eavesdrop on the connection, they may be able to hijack your session by stealing your cookie values.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `requireSSL` attribute to `false`, or remove it (`requireSSL` is false if no value is specified). If `requireSSL` is set to true, then the server will not accept authentication cookies unless they are sent to the server over an HTTPS connection. When this attribute is removed, the server will accept authentication cookies from both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Setting `requireSSL` to false has security implications, as it will be possible for the authentication cookie to be stolen if it is transmitted over an HTTP connection.